# What happens when two threads call the same Client method in a class at the same time?

Tags: java, tcp

```
  public class Atx {
Txlog tlog = new Txlog();

  public static int NO_CON_TIMEOUT;
  public static int SOTIME;


 public void tx(String msg, String ipadress ) throws IOException{
   //  int no_con_timeout =10000;
     int port = 25902;

 try {

     InetAddress IPAddress =InetAddress.getByName(ipadress);
     byte[] byteBuffer =msg.getBytes(); 
   try (Socket client = new Socket()) {
             client.connect(new InetSocketAddress(IPAddress, port), getnocon());
             client.setSoTimeout(getsotime());
             client.setTcpNoDelay(true);
            OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
            InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
            out.write(byteBuffer); // Send the encoded string to the server

            // Receive the same string back from the server
            int totalBytesRcvd = 0; // Total bytes received so far
            int bytesRcvd; // Bytes received in last read
            while (totalBytesRcvd < byteBuffer.length) {
                if ((bytesRcvd = in.read(byteBuffer, totalBytesRcvd,byteBuffer.length - totalBytesRcvd)) == -1)
                    throw new SocketException("Connection closed prematurely");

                totalBytesRcvd +=bytesRcvd;}
            //System.out.println("Received: " + new String(byteBuffer)+ " From: " + ipadress) ;
             if(msg.charAt(0)=='A')
             {tlog.tlog(ipadress , new String(byteBuffer)+ "  Accepted by other"); }
             else
                 if(msg.charAt(0)=='D')
                  {tlog.tlog(ipadress , new String(byteBuffer)+ "   WIFI OOR delay Cancelled"); }  
             client.close();
        }
  }catch(IOException e)
  {
     // System.out.println(e + " to " + ipadress ); 
      if(msg.charAt(0)=='A')
      {tlog.tlog(ipadress , e.getMessage()+ " Accepted by other Not Reached") ;}
      else
      if(msg.charAt(0)=='D')
        {tlog.tlog(ipadress , e.getMessage()+ " WIFI OOR delay Cancelled Not Reached"); }     
  }

}

 public void setnocn(int nocontime) {

    Atx.NO_CON_TIMEOUT=nocontime;

} 

public void setsotime(int sotime) {

    Atx.SOTIME=sotime;

} 

 public int getnocon() {

    return Atx.NO_CON_TIMEOUT;

}

  public int getsotime() {

    return Atx.SOTIME;

}

}
```

If the Frist Thread calls tx(String msg, String ipaddress) while it still processing that what happens if the second thread also calls tx(String msg, String ipaddress). This method just transmit message to server on a TCP port and receives the echo back and closes the connection.

Comment: If is not modifing any external variable/s that is/are used from multiple Threads then i assume is ok,else you have to synchronize the code so one Thread can access the method each time.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It does not modify any external variables. It is a TCP/IP client method and when called opens a port and send the packet and closes the connection.  I am wondering what will happen if it called by the second thread while it is still processing a call from other thread. I assume  from what you have said there won't be any problem